# Integrating multivariable funciton

Tags: plotting, summation

I'm new to Mathematica, and trying to plot a function, but stuck at integrating the function for hours. What I want to do is to plotting the following function with respect to $x$.
$$-\int^1_0\sum^n_{i=1}{n-1\choose i-1}^2(x-y)^2(xy)^{2i-2}(1-x^2)^{n-i}(1-y^2)^{n-i}2ydy$$ 
To do so, I defined a function $h$ which has 4 variable

```
h[x_, y_, i_, n_] = -(Binomial[n - 1, i - 1])^2*((x - y)^2)*(x y)^(2 i - 2) ((1 - x^2) (1 - y^2))^(n - i) 2 y
```

But I can't figure out how to make a summation over $i$ and then how to integrate with respect to $y$.

What should I do if I want to do the integration and summation of this multivariable function?

Comment: You need a space (or `*`) in `xy`.

Comment: I tried Sum[h[*,*,i,n],{i,n}], but it processed nothing..

Comment: First integrating and then doing the summation returns an answer.

Comment: Oh my god.. Thank you so much for the help. It works!!!! By the way, I can remove the $\{x,0,1\}$ term because I integrate only w.r.t. $y$, right?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. One thing I noticed is that If I run the code for $n=2$, n = 2; Integrate[Sum[h[x, y, i, n], {i, 1, n}], {y, 0, 1}], The output has $y$ inside in it. Something like $\frac{1}{6}+\cdots+x^2xy^2$. Why isn't the $y$ term integrated out?

Comment: Your code in the question contains `xy` when it should be either `x y` or `x*y`

Comment: @BobHanlon Wow.. it was my mistake:) Thank you all for the help. This really was a big help to a beginner like me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consolidating comments and using assumptions and simplifications

```
h[x_, y_, i_, 
   n_] = -Binomial[n - 1, i - 1]^2*(x - y)^2*(x y)^(2 i - 
      2) ((1 - x^2) (1 - y^2))^(n - i) 2 y;
```

Integrate each term

```
f[x_, i_, n_] = 
 Assuming[Element[{i, n}, Integers] && 1 <= i <= n, 
  Integrate[h[x, y, i, n], {y, 0, 1}] // Simplify]

(*  -x^(2 (-1 + i)) (1 - x^2)^(-i + n)
  Binomial[-1 + n, -1 + 
   i]^2 (-i + n)! (-((2 x Gamma[1/2 + i])/
    Gamma[3/2 + n]) + ((i + (1 + n) x^2) Gamma[i])/Gamma[2 + n])  *)
```

Sum the integrals

```
g[x_, n_] = 
 Assuming[Element[n, Integers] && n >= 1, 
  Sum[f[x, i, n], {i, n}] // FullSimplify]

(*  -((1 + 2 n x^2)/(n + n^2)) + 
 1/Gamma[3/2 + n] Sqrt[π] x (1 - x^2)^(-1 + n)
    Gamma[n] Hypergeometric2F1[3/2, 1 - n, 1, x^2/(-1 + x^2)]  *)
```

Comment: This is perfect. Thank you so much. Today is my first day studying Mathematica, and this helped me a lot!